# Reading from a file to a list

Tags: java, file, list

I'm trying to create a list from a file, and then use that list in my main class.

Here's my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Read.ReadFile(Read.java:18)
at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        List<Integer> a = (new Read()).ReadFile();

        Read z = new Read();
        z.OpenFile();
        z.ReadFile();
        z.CloseFile();
        System.out.println(a);

    }
}
```

And the other class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Read {
    private Scanner x;

    public void OpenFile(){
        try{
            x = new Scanner(new File("numbers.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> ReadFile(){
        List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(x.hasNextInt()){
            a.add(x.nextInt());
        }
        return a;
    }

    public void CloseFile(){
        x.close();
    }
}
```

And here's my text file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I hope someone can help me.
ps. I'm learning to program on my own and English isn't my first language so I'm sorry if there are beginner mistakes.

Comment: you should initialize the scanner in the read constructor. this way you cant create a read instance with a null scanner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Integer> a = (new Read()).ReadFile();
```

You are calling `ReadFile();` here before opening a file. So, `x` will be null and results in `NullPointerException`.

One way to solve this issue would be:

move `ArrayList<>` inside `Read` class and add `get` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence of statements should be like this:

```
    Read z = new Read();// instantiate the reader
    z.OpenFile(); //open the file
    List<Integer> a = z.ReadFile(); //read and hold the values in array
    z.CloseFile(); //close the file
    System.out.println(a); //print the values
```

No need of first statement. Get the reader, open the file, read the values, close the file and then print the values.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line, you create a new instance of Read and immediately call ReadFile() instead of first creating the Scanner object with OpenFile():

```
    List<Integer> a = (new Read()).ReadFile();
```